# How do i escape aliases in Dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server

I am getting an error near Alias Names i.e., `Month_Name`, `Limit_Mins`, `Amount` in this dynamic sql, how do i resolve that , i tried with adding one more quote, but when i do tyhat i am only getting `@columnames` into the sql. How do i resolve the error and make it part of the string

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
    SELECT
       @columns = coalesce(@columns + ',', '') + quotename(Limit_Mins) 
    from
       (
          select DISTINCT
    (L.Limit_Mins ) as 'Limit_Mins' 
          from
             Limit L 
       )
       AS lIMITS 


       SELECT @columns 


       SET
          @sql = 'select * from (
     
          SELECT
             month (Sa.[Date]) AS 'Month_Name',
             convert(varchar(10), 
             case
                when
                   S.Limit_Mins = L.Limit_Mins 
                   and S.Childcare_Flag = 1 
                then
                   S.Limit_Mins 
                else
                   0 
             end
    ) as 'Limit_Mins', sum(
             case
                when
                   S.Childcare_Flag = 1 
                   and S.Limit_Mins = L.Limit_Mins 
                then
                   case
                      when
                         D.PID = Sa.PID 
                         and D.Discount_Date = Sa.[Date] 
                      then
                         D.Discount_Price 
                      else
                         P.Retail_price 
                   end
                   *Sa.Quantity 
                   else
                      0 
             end
    ) as 'Amount' 
          FROM
             Limit L 
             join
                Store S 
                on L.Limit_Mins = S.Limit_Mins 
             join
                Sale Sa 
                on S.Store_Number = Sa.Store_number 
             join
                [Date] Dt 
                on Dt.[Date] = Sa.[Date] 
             join
                Product P 
                on Sa.PID = P.PID 
             left outer join
                Discount D 
                on Sa.PID = D.PID 
                and Sa.[Date] = D.Discount_Date 
          WHERE
             Sa.[Date] >= DATEADD(year, - 1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)) 
             AND Sa.[Date] < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)            --   DATEDIFF(MM,Sale.[Date] ,GETDATE())<=12
             --and Sale.[Date]  < DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
          GROUP BY
             month(Sa.[Date]) , 
             case
                when
                   S.Limit_Mins = L.Limit_Mins 
                   and S.Childcare_Flag = 1 
                then
                   S.Limit_Mins 
                else
                   0 
             end
          union all
          SELECT
             month (Sa.[Date]) AS 'Month_Name',
             ''No Childcare'' as 'Limit_Mins',
             isnull(sum(
             case
                when
                   S.Childcare_Flag = 0 
                then
                   case
                      when
                         D.PID = Sa.PID 
                         and D.Discount_Date = Sa.[Date] 
                      then
                         D.Discount_Price 
                      else
                         P.Retail_price 
                   end
                   *Sa.Quantity 
                   else
                      0 
             end
    ), 0) as 'Sales_Amount' 
          FROM
             Store S 
             join
                Sale Sa 
                on S.Store_Number = Sa.Store_number 
             join
                [Date] Dt 
                on Dt.[Date] = Sa.[Date] 
             join
                Product P 
                on Sa.PID = P.PID 
             left outer join
                Discount D 
                on Sa.PID = D.PID 
                and Sa.[Date] = D.Discount_Date 
          WHERE
             Sa.[Date] >= DATEADD(year, - 1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)) 
             AND Sa.[Date] < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)            --   DATEDIFF(MM,Sale.[Date] ,GETDATE())<=12
             --and Sale.[Date]  < DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
          GROUP BY
             month(Sa.[Date])
    )
    A PIVOT(sum(Amount) for Limit_Mins in 
    (
       '+@columns+
     ',[No Childcare]
     
    )
    )as PIVOTTable 
    order by
       [Month]'
     print @sql
```

Comment: Single quotes are string delimiters. Use `[alias]` or `"alias"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use brackets instead of quotes: `month (Sa.[Date]) AS [Month_Name],`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the quotes earlier, but it was throwing an error invalid column which i later realized was happening because i renamed the alias and forgot to rename the same column order by , Thanks for the input